# javascript reduce gets undefined

Tags: javascript, reduce

I am getting undefined. The code works without the function. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var myArr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];

function getSums(arr) {
  arr.reduce(a => a+1, 0);
}

document.write(getSums(myArr));
```

Comment: You need to `return` from function.

Comment: @nenad this is an arrow function and it has RETURN in it by default?

Comment: `getSums` is not an arrow function.

Comment: @juhana ohhhhhh now I see. thank you

Comment: Here is your arrow: `const getSums = arr => arr.reduce((sum, a) => sum + a);`

Answer (score 4):

Three issues:

1. When using `reduce`, you use the first **two** arguments (at least): The accumulator, and the current entry. (It has other arguments as well, but the first two are the ones used most often.)
2. Your logic was just doing `a + 1`, which isn't adding values from the array together, it's adding `1` to the value for that entry.
3. You need to *return* the value returned by `reduce` from your `getSums` function.

So:

```js
var myArr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];

function getSums(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((sum, a) => sum + a, 0);
//^^^^^^            ^^^^   ^    ^^^^^^
}

console.log(getSums(myArr));
```

Or you could define `getSums` using arrow syntax, and then the return would be implied if you use a concise function body:

```js
var myArr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];

let getSums = arr => arr.reduce((sum, a) => sum + a, 0);

console.log(getSums(myArr));
```

Comment: You don't need to pass an initial value to reduce since your wrapper doesn't except one.

Comment: @LUH3417: The callbacks to `reduce` **always** accept the accumulator, it's the first argument. It's true that we could leave the `, 0` off the calls in this particular case, because it's a summing operation. I usually prefer the clarity of having it, but it's a style thing.